# Variable value not showing up

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

After executing the following script I'm unable to view the value of the property `name` in the `$demo1` variable, but for the variable `$demo` I'm able to see the property values for all the properties. Can anyone help me with this one?

Note: Both the variables are of same type (`Selected.System.Data.DataRow`).

`$demo.drive` is working, `$demo1.name` or `$demo1.log_size_in_mb` or `$demo1.db_size_in_mb` is not working.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
$serverInstance = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.server')
$db = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database')

$db = $serverinstance.Databases.Item("Master")

$ds = $db.ExecuteWithResults("xp_fixeddrives")

$ds1 = $db.ExecuteWithResults("select dbid
,d.name
,d.compatibility_level
,d.recovery_model_desc
,convert(decimal(18,2),(sum(size)*8)/1024.0) as db_size_in_mb
,(select (size*8)/1024.0 from sys.sysaltfiles where dbid=saf.dbid and groupid=0) as log_size_in_mb
from sys.sysaltfiles saf
join sys.databases d on saf.dbid=d.database_id
where groupid>0
group by dbid,d.name,d.compatibility_level,d.recovery_model_desc")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ds.Tables.Count; $i++) {
    $res = $ds.Tables[$i]
}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ds1.Tables.Count; $i++) {
    $res1 = $ds1.Tables[$i]
}

$demo1 = @()
$demo  = $res | select PSComputerName, Drive, 'MB Free'
$demo1 = $res1 | select Name, recovery_model_desc, db_size_in_mb, log_size_in_mb

$demo1.name
```

Comment: Works on my system without any issues, so this might be version or config specific a problem. Does the `$res1` contain sensible data at all?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you querying? `sys.sysaltfiles` is deprecated, you may have more luck with the [`sys.master_files`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx) view

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: sysaltfiles is also giving back the results as expected, its just that iam unable to retrieve the property value from the variable.

Comment: @vonPryz: which version of powershell are you using? I'm using V2

Comment: Does `$res1` actually contain a table? Also, why are assigning tables to a variable in a loop if you're going to keep only the last one anyway?

Comment: the for loop is for when the script is used for multiple computers, even when we do this "$res1  = $ds1.Tables[0]", $res1 will have a table with ~4 rows and when we pass the value to $demo1 the property value doesn't show up. However, $res has only one row and when passed the value to $demo, i can see the property values of "drive" & "MB Free" columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PowerShell v2 and `$demo1` contains an array (multiple table rows). Automatic unrolling (the ability to access properties or methods of array *elements* by calling the property or method on the array *object*) was introduced with PowerShell v3.

In PowerShell v2 `$array.Name` will try to get the value of a property `Name` *of the array object itself*. Since the array object doesn't have such a property this returns `$null`.

What you need to do is get the desired property of the individual array elements, for instance like this:

```
$demo1 | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

or like this:

```
$demo1 | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
```